# i have a problem with my c# weighting scale program

Tags: c#

i have made a c# windows forms app that receives weight from a weighting scale through rs-232 serial
communication. so basically when i press button1 i should get the weight into label1.
except when i press the button1 for the second time an exception error occurs. it says the port is already opened or already used.what should i do?

```
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace loaded
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort rs;
        string Data;
        private delegate void setlbtext(string text, Label lb);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rs= new SerialPort();
            rs.BaudRate = 9600;
            rs.Parity = Parity.None;
            rs.DataBits = 8;
            rs.PortName = "COM7";

            rs.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Rsrecivedata);
        }

        private void Rsrecivedata (object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Data = rs.ReadLine();
            updatalabel(Data, label1);
        }

        private void updatalabel (string value, Label lb)
        {
            if (lb.InvokeRequired)
            {
                lb.Invoke(new setlbtext(updatalabel), value, lb);
            }
            else
            {
                lb.Text = value;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rs.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pressing the *Enter* key when a `Button` has focus will click it. That suggest that you are clicking your `Button` twice so you're trying to open the `SerialPort` twice, so of course you get that message. Why are you pressing *Enter* in the first place? Maybe you should be disabling that `Button` until you close the `SerialPort`, so you can't click it more than once.

Comment: i meant when i click on the button not pressing the enter key

Comment: You probably ought to edit your question and provide truthful information then, because misleading us about the problem is not a great way to get help.

Comment: Does it happen the very first time you click the `Button` or not until the second time?

Comment: the second time, the first time nothing happens. it doesnt read the weight from the weighting scale

Comment: In the button click event handler, you should check first if the port is already open before doing `rs.Open();`. If the port is already open you should skip opening it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: @Chetan how? i'm new to programming

Comment: @Chetan didnt work bro but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you click the button, you are trying to open the serial connection. But after the first click, that port is already open and you get an exception.
How to solve this:

- Open the Com-port in the `Form1_Load` method.
- In `Rsrecivedata` you can update the label immediately (so no button is needed) or you can just buffer the received value in a string field (and update the label from that field in `button1_Click`.
- Make sure you close the serial port when the form is Closed (using the `Closing`event?). Otherwise the port will stau open and you will get an exception the next time the form is loaded.

That would be something like this:

```
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace loaded
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort rs;
        string Data;
        private delegate void setlbtext(string text, Label lb);

        private string buffer = string.Empty;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rs= new SerialPort();
            rs.BaudRate = 9600;
            rs.Parity = Parity.None;
            rs.DataBits = 8;
            rs.PortName = "COM7";

            rs.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Rsrecivedata);
            rs.Open();    
            this.Closing += Form1_Closing; 
        }

        private void Rsrecivedata (object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Data = rs.ReadLine();
            buffer = Data;
        }

        private void updatalabel (string value, Label lb)
        {
            if (lb.InvokeRequired)
            {
                lb.Invoke(new setlbtext(updatalabel), value, lb);
            }
            else
            {
                lb.Text = value;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            updatalabel(buffer, label1);
        }

        private void Form1_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          rs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the thing is when i press the button once nothing happens, by that i mean it doesnt read the weight from the weighting scale

Comment: but can you help me with your answer? because im new to c#.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: The code you provided will update the label when data is received from the serial port. But there are a few things that can go wrong: is the scale really connected tot Com7? are the settings (especially the baudrate) correct? When does the scale send  its data (check in the documentation if you need to prompt it with some command)...

Comment: To check what goes wrong: try to learn debugging your code by placing breakpoints at strategic positions (e.g. in the `Rsrecivedata` method to check if the scale sends data).

Comment: And something to consider: does the scale effectively send the value as a string followed by an 'end-of-line' or 'carriage return'  character (which is what `ReadLine` expects)?

Comment: thank you very much it helped alot, just one more problem, it cant read the weight idk why no matter how much i ty

Comment: @Ahmed: that is not very specific.  Do you get an exception?  Does the scale send a string?

Comment: well, the label becomes empty. i dont get either error nor exception. it just doesnt read the weight

Comment: You could set a breakpoint in the `Rsrecivedata` method. If that is never hit, the scale simply does not send any serial data. If the breakpoint is hit, you can check the string that is read (does the scale really send a string?).

Comment: Thank you but how do I do that? I’m new

Comment: A good start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022 or https://code-maze.com/debugging-csharp-visual-studio/

Comment: ok thanks i get it, but which line should i set a breakpoint to?

Comment: See my previous comments...

Answer (score 0):

A serial port cannot be opened twice, once you open a serial port:

- You just can't open it again, that's why you get the **the port is already opened or already used** exception, try this:

  ```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (!rs.IsOpen)
      {
          rs.Open();
      }
  }
  ```
- Make sure to close the serial port when closing the application, **otherwise you will not be able to open it after restarting application**:

  ```
  private void Form1_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      rs.Close();
  }
  ```

And you should already be able to get your weight value refreshed every time on **rs.DataReceived** triggered.

Comment: but the problem is to actually "get" the weight value into the label, or into a textbox